# Title for tikzpicture flowchart

Tags: tikz-trees

I created a rather big flowchart with tikz and want to have my parent node as a header – without a line drawn from it down and without the box around the text – but keeping its central position.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}% <-- new
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center, fill=white},  level distance=3cm,            
level 1/.style = {sibling distance = 20em},% <-- new
level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 50em},% <-- new
level 3/.style = {sibling distance = 30em},% <-- new
level 4/.style = {sibling distance = 30em},
level 5/.style = {sibling distance = 35em},
level 6/.style = {sibling distance = 30em},
level 7/.style = {sibling distance = 30em},
level 8/.style = {sibling distance = 30em},
level 9/.style = {sibling distance = 20em},
level 10/.style = {sibling distance = 20em},
% <-- new
]

\node {Metaethische Positionen}
[edge from parent fork down]
child {node {Ethische Urteile wie »Foltern ist falsch« \\
       drücken Überzeugungen aus.}
child{node{Ja: Kognitivismus}child{node{Erfolgstheorie: \\ 
           Einige moralische Urteile sind wahr}
child{node{Die Wahrheit moralischer \\
           Urteile verdankt sich \\
           der Übereinstimmung mit der Realität}
 child{node{Ja}
 child{node{Substantieller\\ Realismus}
 child{node{Reduktionistischer naturalistischer Realismus\\
            moralische Eigenschaften lassen sich auf \\ 
            natürliche Eigenschaften reduzieren}}
 child{node{Non-Naturalistischer Realismus\\ 
            moralische Eigenschaften\\
            sind von eigener Art}   }}}
 child{node{Nein}
 child{node{Prozeduraler Realismus:\\ 
            Die Wahrheit moralischer Urteile \\ 
            verdankt sich einem Verfahren}}}}}
 child{node{Irrtumstheorie:\\ 
            Alle moralischen Urteile sind falsch }}}
 child{node{Nein:Nonkognitivismus}
 child{node{Emotivismus\\ 
            moralische Urteile\\ 
            als Ausdruck von Emotionen\\ 
           (Ayer, Stevenson)}}
 child{node{Präskriptivismus:\\ 
            die primäre Funktion moralischer Urteile\\
            ist deren handlungsleitende Funktion (R.\,M. Hare)}}}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: define two column style: one for "title" nodes", one for other nodes.  ...For edges, which  you not like to draw use `edge from parent[draw=none]`

Comment: I am sorry but I don’t get it. What exactly do I have to change?

Comment: sorry, instead column style should be "node style". but as I see, meanwhile you got answer, where this is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need two small additions to your tree, marked by comments in the code below: a `[draw=none]` for the first node, and a `edge from parent[draw=none]` in the first `child`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}% <-- new
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center, fill=white},  level distance=3cm,            
level 1/.style = {sibling distance = 20em},% <-- new
level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 50em},% <-- new
level 3/.style = {sibling distance = 30em},% <-- new
level 4/.style = {sibling distance = 30em},
level 5/.style = {sibling distance = 35em},
level 6/.style = {sibling distance = 30em},
level 7/.style = {sibling distance = 30em},
level 8/.style = {sibling distance = 30em},
level 9/.style = {sibling distance = 20em},
level 10/.style = {sibling distance = 20em},
% <-- new
]

\node [draw=none] {Metaethische Positionen} % note added [draw=none]
[edge from parent fork down]
child {node {Ethische Urteile wie »Foltern ist falsch« \\
       drücken Überzeugungen aus.} edge from parent[draw=none] %% <---- added
child{node{Ja: Kognitivismus}child{node{Erfolgstheorie: \\ 
           Einige moralische Urteile sind wahr}
child{node{Die Wahrheit moralischer \\
           Urteile verdankt sich \\
           der Übereinstimmung mit der Realität}
 child{node{Ja}
 child{node{Substantieller\\ Realismus}
 child{node{Reduktionistischer naturalistischer Realismus\\
            moralische Eigenschaften lassen sich auf \\ 
            natürliche Eigenschaften reduzieren}}
 child{node{Non-Naturalistischer Realismus\\ 
            moralische Eigenschaften\\
            sind von eigener Art}   }}}
 child{node{Nein}
 child{node{Prozeduraler Realismus:\\ 
            Die Wahrheit moralischer Urteile \\ 
            verdankt sich einem Verfahren}}}}}
 child{node{Irrtumstheorie:\\ 
            Alle moralischen Urteile sind falsch }}}
 child{node{Nein:Nonkognitivismus}
 child{node{Emotivismus\\ 
            moralische Urteile\\ 
            als Ausdruck von Emotionen\\ 
           (Ayer, Stevenson)}}
 child{node{Präskriptivismus:\\ 
            die primäre Funktion moralischer Urteile\\
            ist deren handlungsleitende Funktion (R.\,M. Hare)}}}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with tree title in separate node:

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, trees}% <-- added positioning
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
level distance=25mm,
level 1/.style = {sibling distance = 40em},% <-- changed
level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 20em},% <-- changed
                    ]
% node for tree title
\node (title)   [font=\large\bfseries] {Metaethische Positionen}; 
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=white, % <-- added scope, 
                                                                          % with definition for nodes style
                                       inner sep=2mm, align=center}]
% start of tree
\node [below=of title]  {Ethische Urteile wie »Foltern ist falsch« \\
                         drücken Überzeugungen aus.} 
       [edge from parent fork down]%
child{node{Ja: Kognitivismus}
    child{node{Erfolgstheorie: \\
               Einige moralische Urteile sind wahr}
        child{node{Die Wahrheit moralischer \\
                   Urteile verdankt sich \\
                   der Übereinstimmung mit der Realität}
            child{node{Ja}
                child{node{Substantieller\\ Realismus}
                    child{node{Reduktionistischer naturalistischer Realismus\\
                               moralische Eigenschaften lassen sich auf \\
                               natürliche Eigenschaften reduzieren}}
                child{node{Non-Naturalistischer Realismus\\
                           moralische Eigenschaften\\
                           sind von eigener Art}   }
                    }
                }
            child{node{Nein}
                child{node{Prozeduraler Realismus:\\
                           Die Wahrheit moralischer Urteile \\
                           verdankt sich einem Verfahren}}
                }
            }
        }
child{node{Irrtumstheorie:\\
           Alle moralischen Urteile sind falsch }}
    }
child{node{Nein:Nonkognitivismus}
    child{node{Emotivismus\\
               moralische Urteile\\
               als Ausdruck von Emotionen\\
               (Ayer, Stevenson)}}
    child{node{Präskriptivismus:\\
               die primäre Funktion moralischer Urteile\\
               ist deren handlungsleitende Funktion\\ 
               (R.\,M. Hare)}}
    }
    ;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]